# How can I use an implict variable when return type contingent on switch statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want to be able to assign the results from a database query into a single, generic variable.

The issue is that each query returns a slightly different return type. I cannot initialize an implicit variable (i.e. `var data;`) as this gives an error.

The `foreach` statement performs the same operation on `data` so I'd like to populate `data` based on the `viewtype` parameter.

```
ITableRepository tableRepository = new TableRepository(); 

var data; \\Gives me an error

switch (viewtype)
{
    case "overall": \\ type = IEnumerable<usp_GetTableRankingResult> 
        data = tableRepository.GetTableRanking(1, null); 
        break; 
    case "week": \\ type = IEnumerable<usp_GetTableRankingThisWeekResult> 
        data = tableRepository.GetTableRankingThisWeek(1, null); 
        break;
    case "minileague": \\ type = IEnumerable<usp_GetTableRankingMimiLeagueResult> 
        data = tableRepository.GetTableRankingMiniLeague(1, null); 
        break;
}

foreach (var item in data) { //do some stuff }
```

I cannot initialize the `data` variable inside the switch statement and I cannot explicit declare the `data` variable upfront e.g. `IEnumerable<usp_GetTableRankingResult> data` as I don't know what type it will be until runtime.

Who can show me a way forward?

Comment: Any chance that the different types all derive from a common base class?

Comment: A common abstract base class/interface and your `data` can be of that type.

Comment: You tell me what type "item" is, and I can answer your question...

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta. The types don't derive from a common base class. They are all auto-generated by Linq-to-Sql when I map my stored procedures I am using to grab data from the database.

Comment: Ahah. If you cannot tell me, how do you expect Linq2Sql to solve this for you..

Answer (score 1):

You can't separate declaration and initialisation when using `var`.

When you use `var`, you ask the compiler to guess the type based on the initialiser:

```
//  v--------------- Set the type of the declared identifier "data"
//         v-------- from the inferred type of its initializer
var data = ...
```

So you can only use `var` with an initialiser. Your `var data;` doesn't have any.

---

The way forward depends on what's in "do some stuff". I'd imagine something like

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> data;

switch (viewtype) 
...
```

for some suitable type `SomeType`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Queti mentions in his comment: let each of the `GetTableRanking...()` methods return an enumerable of a base type, like `IEnumerable<TableRanking>`.

Then you can declare data like this:

```
IEnumerable<TableRanking> data;
```

The compiler will then complain about the use of `data` in your `foreach`, because it may not have been initialized by the `switch` block. Select one default case (like `overall`) and promote that to default:

```
switch (viewtype)
{
    // ...
    default:
        data = tableRepository.GetTableRanking(1, null); 
        break; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The problem i think is that the different types (e.g. `usp_...` don't derive from a common base class. They are all auto-generated by Linq-to-Sql when I map my stored procedures into VS2008.

Comment: ORMs really are a pain for this reason, you could always create the data object as an object type (IEnumberable<object> data;) and then cast it after the switch statement based on what I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The idea here would be to Setup the Possible items as an inherited child of a base

```
public class usp_GetTableRankingResult{
    // shared properties
}

public class usp_GetTableRankingsByWeek : usp_GetTableRankingResult{
    // extra properies for this guy
}    

public class usp_GetTableRankingsByDay : usp_GetTableRankingsResult{
    // extra propries for this guy
}

// and so on
```

and when you're ready to implement you do this

```
IEnumerable<usp_GetTableRankingsResult> results;

switch(viewType){
     case "overall":
         results = new List<usp_GetTableRankingsResults>();
         // fill results or use another implementation of IEnumerable or whatever...
         break;
      case "week":
         results = new List<usp_GetTableRankingsResultsByWeek>();
         // fill results or use another implementation of IEnumerable or whatever...
         break;
      case "day":
         results = new List<usp_GetTableRankingsResultsByDay>();
         // fill results or use another implementation of IEnumerable or whatever...
         break;
}
```

and then later you can do something like this to get the result specific data

```
foreach(var result in results){
    if (result is usp_GetTableRankinsResultByDay){
        // do specifics if its by Day
    }
    // and so on
}
```